# Can I edit a post, just to add tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits, edit-ban

Suppose I see a question with just one tag or two and it OBVIOUSLY has code, etc. relating to another tag, but the question itself is fine..

I understand I don't get any reputation points - that's not the issue.

My edits still go through peer review, I have 745 reputation points on Stack Overflow.

Can I edit the tags only without getting an edit ban?

Comment: I think the downvotes stem from a combination of "there's a lot of information on retagging", "there's a retag link right there, so you can do that" and "why is OP concerned about the ban...sounds fishy".

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby why IS that fishy?  I have received edit bans before and want to make sure I'm doing the right thing. OMG Please man. Sometimes a boot is just a boot. Not a device with a hidden agenda. And where is the re-tag link - look before you leap Mr.

Comment: What part of "I think the downvotes stem from..." didn't you get? I also *might* have downvoted if I would have found a duplicate to this, but unfortunately there is no FAQ on retagging...oh wait, there is one on suggesting edits, hang on...ah, damn, that doesn't cover retaggings either. I think we need an FAQ entry for that.

Comment: Why would they have an option for retagging (and a separate privilege level for it) if it weren't allowed?

Comment: @Juhana there is no option for me to retag, I have to do it via an edit

Comment: They removed only the retag link but behind the scenes it still exists. Editing and only changing tags is just retagging and when you have 500+ rep it does not become suggested edit. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17041220/2), it says "edited" and not "suggested". (example for [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17041624/2)).

Comment: Actually I just answered your comment "there is no option for me to retag, I have to do it via an edit". As for the real question is retag only edits are fine then yes, it's fine that what the retag exists for. Having 500 rep means the system count on you to choose tags properly.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The retag link has not been removed, it is just a bit hidden. When you hover a question's tags, the "edit tags" link will appear at the right of the last tag. At least that is what happens for me on Main.

Comment: @Yvette None of those changes look incorrect to me, but they shouldn't have taken so many edits to all get made. Correcting spelling and grammar is one of the reasons you **should** edit a post.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté it appears only for 10K+ users, the retag link used to be next to "edit" and "share" for those with 500 to 2000 reputation. (as far as I can remember)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh I see. I thought they had just changed the retag link into this edit tags link. My bad. `:P`

Comment: @Yvette Care to link me directly to the part of the FAQ you're referring to? Had all of the issues with your post been resolved in one comprehensive edit that would have been a completely valid one, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I've expressed *my opinion* about the validity of the edits; if there's something in the FAQ I've missed that contradicts that I'd like to read it so I can *revise my opinion*. If you're going to just act like everybody is out to get you, however, then you're right - this is a waste of time. Rolling back to an objectively worse version of the post just because the improvements were done in a series of edits is ridiculous, in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe this is a little late, but anyways: I didn’t edit and roll back your question for fun. Your self-answer was flagged as not an answer, I converted it to an edit, and then decided I’d made a mistake. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you reach 500 reputation retagging doesn't go to the review queue. It's approved automatically. Since the edit can't be rejected it can't count towards the edit ban.

A more interesting question would be if retagging after 500 rep counts *positively* when the system considers the edit ban, or are only reviewed edits taken into account.

Comment: You can ask that question

Comment: Only reviewed edits are taken into account. Note that you also can't retag using the normal [edit] link until you reach the 2k edit anything privilege.